# My solr service doesn't appear to be applying stopwords and synonyms

Tags: solr

This is a copy of my "text" fieldtype.  When i type in a query, synonyms and stopwords are not being respected.  However, the WordDelimiterFilterFactor is working as expected....Is something wrong with my schema?

http://pastebin.com/i552PCAE  (same code is found here)

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
<!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
          add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
          analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the stopwords.txt file is in the correct conf directory and has stopwords in it.cant think of any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
expand=true
```

depending on your synonyms file this will match all synonyms (so won't replace one with another)

```
# If expand==true, "ipod, i-pod, i pod" is equivalent to the explicit mapping:
ipod, i-pod, i pod => ipod, i-pod, i pod
# If expand==false, "ipod, i-pod, i pod" is equivalent to the explicit mapping:
ipod, i-pod, i pod => ipod
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory