# Solr stopwords issue - documents are not matching

Tags: solr

I am using solr-3.4, My part of schema looks like,

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

stopwords_en.txt contains
a
an
and
are
as

etc..

Now when I search for "**buy house**" Solr does not return me the documents with text "**buy a house**".
Also when I search for "**buy a house**" Solr does not return me the documents with text "**buy house**".

A part of debugQuery is

```
<str name="rawquerystring">cContent:"buy a house"</str>
<str name="querystring">cContent:"buy a house"</str>
<str name="parsedquery">PhraseQuery(cContent:"bui ? hous")</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">cContent:"bui ? hous"</str>
```

Similar (but not exact) question was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632497/my-solr-service-doesnt-appear-to-be-applying-stopwords-and-synonyms)
But there was no satisfactory answer to solve this problem.

Any idea how can I solve this problem? or what is wrong?

Comment: Could you go to Solr Admin analysis page (http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/analysis.jsp?highlight=on) and post index & query analysis for "buy a house" (check verbose output) ?

Comment: Due to character-limit can't paste here. But I have put that here (http://ameykpatil.weebly.com/solrimage.html)

Answer (score 3):

You are searching with a PhraseQuery so in the first case of "buy house" won't match "buy a house". If you add slop (cContent:"buy house"~2) to the PhraseQuery you will also get matches.

In the second case although the stopword is filtered out it still expects something to be on that position, so "buy a house" will match on "buy one house", but not on "buy house". Maybe slop can fix this too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks O.Klein, that will help too some extent, still I'll have to think for 2nd case and to eliminate cases like "buy white house" etc which will get caught when I use slop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think your problem is with the PorterStemmer - "house" is being transformed to "hous". Unless you really think you need it, I would turn off the porter stemmer. In my experience, it usually does more harm than good.